# Error on loading user control

Tags: c#, .net, object, user-controls, devexpress

i want to load my own designed User Control to the form but when i drag and place the
 user Control it produces the Error. Please Kindly refer my Screen Shot and help me to solve 
this issue.

[image]

**The error where in code is i mentioned as line no:**

```
private void populateTransfers(bool all)
        {
            AccountTransfer[] accounts;

            //List<ReferenceData._account> headers = ReferenceData.getIndentHeader_account();

            if (all)
                accounts = accountClient.getAllPendingTransfers();
            else
                accounts = accountClient.getPendingTransfers(Program.loggedInUser.account.id);//line no:47

            if (accounts != null)
            {
                var query = from a in accounts
                            select new
                            {
                                Id = a.id,
                                Name=a.name,                                    
                                Status = a.status,
                                Date = a.ludt.ToShortDateString()
                            };

                this.gridPendingTransfers.DataSource = query.ToList();
                this.gridPendingTransfers.RefreshDataSource();
            }
            else
            {
                CexAppUtil.ShowEmptyGrid("No pending transfers", this.gridPendingTransfers);
            }

private void initializeData()
        {
            if (Program.loggedInUser != null && Program.loggedInUser.isAdmin())
            {
                pendingTransferOptionsPanel.Visible = true;
                showAllPendingTransfers.Visible = true;
                if (showAllPendingTransfers.Checked) populateTransfers(true);
                else populateTransfers(false);
            }
            else
            {
                pendingTransferOptionsPanel.Visible = false;
                showAllPendingTransfers.Visible = false;
                populateTransfers(false);//line no:167
            }
        }
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

Thanks-in Advance.

Comment: Perhaps `accountClient` is null?

Comment: Are doing some work in constructor? Delete all code from constructor instead of InitilizeComponents(). Then make a new Initilize Method where you copy the code from constructor. This method you call in form.load or sth. Try it out ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can debug and find the error in your custom control by starting a new instance of visual studio and attach the debugger to the process of the first instance.
After that you can add your new control and see which object is null.

Answer (score 0):

Are doing some work in constructor? Delete all code from constructor instead of InitilizeComponents(). Then make a new Initilize Method where you copy the code from constructor. This method you call in form.load or sth. Try it out ;) –  @ Sebi

Thank to every-one.